# Flutter FireStore, Update TimeStamp with current time plus 5 minutes

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Im writing data into Firestore DB, Im successfully writing it, as well then reading it based on TimeStamp order.

Now I would like to update TimeStamp of certain listId with current time plus 5 minutes, but can't figure it out, Was checking online, but only examples I was able to find were for other languages than dart, and couldn't figure it out.

Write Data

```
Future<void> addSentences(String listId) {
  final Sentences = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Sentences');
  return Sentences.add({
    'listId': listId,
    'timeStamp': Timestamp.now(),
  });
}
```

Get oldest listId

```
 void getOldestListId() async {
      await for (var messages
          in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Sentences").orderBy("timeStamp").limit(1).snapshots()) {
        for (var message in messages.docs.toList()) {
          print(message.data());
          Map we = message.data();
          print(we['listId']);
        }
      }
    }
```

Tried to update timeStamp with TimeStamp.now() plus 5 minutes, but can't figure how to do it

```
void update() async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sentences');
    collection
        .doc(listId) // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
        .update(timeStamp: Timestamp.now() + minutes(5));
  }
```

EDIT

Please note that `listId` is value Im saving into Firestore database and not document Id so it can't be inserted into `.doc(listId)`, when I replace `listId` with document Id I see in Firestore DB `.doc('idCopiedFromFireBaseConsole'),` then I can update timeStamp with current time timeStamp, but still I don't know how to get document Id, I guess I should get document Id in `getOldestListId()` function, how could I get proper Id there?

```
 void getOldestListId() async {
      await for (var messages
          in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Sentences").orderBy("timeStamp").limit(1).snapshots()) {
        for (var message in messages.docs.toList()) {
          print(message.data());
          Map we = message.data();
          print(we['listId']);
        }
      }
    }
```

This is how I can update timeStamp with current time + 5 minutes

```
void update() async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sentences');    collection.doc('idCopiedFromFireBaseConsole').update({'timeStamp': DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 5))});
```

EDIT
Now it works as I expected it to work, posting code for others with similar issue

Function to add data to FireStore

```
  Future<void> addSentences(String sentenceId) {
      final sentences = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sentences');
      return sentences.add({
        'sentenceId': sentenceId,
        'timeStamp': Timestamp.now(),
      });
    }
```

Loop in which `addSentences()` is being used to add data to Firestore DB

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
          //_sentenceList.length
          addChineseSentences(i.toString());
        }
```

Function to get oldest sentenceId

```
 late String _docId;
    void getOldestSentence() async {
      await for (var messages
          in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("sentences").orderBy("timeStamp").limit(1).snapshots()) {
        for (var message in messages.docs.toList()) {
          _docId = message.id;
          print(_docId);
          Map we = message.data();
          print(we['listId']);
        }
      }
    }
```

Function to update sentence timeStamp

```
void updateSentence() async {
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sentences');
  collection.doc(_docId) // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
      .update({'timeStamp': Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 5)))});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try with:

```
collection
    .doc(listId) // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
    .update(timeStamp: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 5))));
```

Comment: collection.doc('idCopiedFromFireBaseConsole').update({'timeStamp': DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 5))}); This is how I can update timeStamp with current time plus 5 minutes. Still don't know how to get document Id

Comment: Ive added to my question under Edit in which I further explain my issue, if you can check it it will help you better understand my issue

Comment: thank, I figured it all out just have some minor issues, will post code when have it all working

Comment: Can you help with a work around? I need to be able to set a timestamp for Jnuary first in the the next year. It's for subscription creation and needs to be 01/01 in the previous year in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

That should be something like this:

```
collection
    .doc(listId)
    .update(timeStamp: Timestamp(Timestamp.now(). millisecondsSinceEpoch + 5*60*1000);
```

The `Timestamp.now(). millisecondsSinceEpoch`  gives you the current time in milliseconds, then we add 5 minutes in milliseconds to it, and convert the combined value back into a `Timestamp`.

Comment: error: 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found. (not_enough_positional_arguments at... Also listId isn't Id of document but Id im saving in Firestore, how can I get document Id?

Comment: thank, I figured it all out just have some minor issues, will post code when have it all working